# When utilizing Flutter audioplayers 6.0.0 to play an audio file, an error occurs during playback

Tags: flutter, flutter-audioplayers

I'm making an app where audio files will be be played. For this purpose, I am using audioplayers 6.0.0. However, despite the fact that the audio is played, I get the same error being displayed multiple times:

> AudioPlayers Exception: AudioPlayerException(
> null,
> UnimplementedError: Event Method does not exist audio.onCurrentPosition
> #0      EventChannelAudioplayersPlatform.createEventStream.<anonymous closure> (package:audioplayers_platform_interface/src/audioplayers_platform.dart:273:13)
> #1      _MapStream._handleData (dart:async/stream_pipe.dart:213:31)
> #2      _ForwardingStreamSubscription._handleData (dart:async/stream_pipe.dart:153:13)
> #3      _RootZone.runUnaryGuarded (dart:async/zone.dart:1594:10)
> #4      _BufferingStreamSubscription._sendData (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:339:11)
> #5      _DelayedData.perform (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:515:14)
> #6      _PendingEvents.handleNext (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:620:11)
> #7      _PendingEvents.schedule.<anonymous closure> (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:591:7)
> #8      _microtaskLoop (dart:async/schedule_microtask.dart:40:21)
> #9      _startMicrotaskLoop (dart:async/schedule_microtask.dart:49:5)
>
> flutter: AudioPlayers Exception: AudioPlayerException(
> null,
> UnimplementedError: Event Method does not exist audio.onCurrentPosition
> #0      EventChannelAudioplayersPlatform.createEventStream.<anonymous closure> (package:audioplayers_platform_interface/src/audioplayers_platform.dart:273:13)
> #1      _MapStream._handleData (dart:async/stream_pipe.dart:213:31)
> #2      _ForwardingStreamSubscription._handleData (dart:async/stream_pipe.dart:153:13)
> #3      _RootZone.runUnaryGuarded (dart:async/zone.dart:1594:10)
> #4      _BufferingStreamSubscription._sendData (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:339:11)
> #5      _DelayedData.perform (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:515:14)
> #6      _PendingEvents.handleNext (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:620:11)
> #7      _PendingEvents.schedule.<anonymous closure> (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:591:7)
> #8      _microtaskLoop (dart:async/schedule_microtask.dart:40:21)
> #9      _startMicrotaskLoop (dart:async/schedule_microtask.dart:49:5)

This is my code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:flutter_application_test/screens/intro_screen.dart';

void main() async {
runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
const MyApp({Key? key});

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return MaterialApp(
title: 'Flutter Demo',
theme: ThemeData(
colorScheme: ColorScheme.fromSeed(seedColor: Colors.lightBlue),
useMaterial3: true,
),
home: const LogInScreen(title: 'Self-anamnesis'),
);
}
}

class LogInScreen extends StatefulWidget {
const LogInScreen({Key? key, required this.title});

final String title;

@override
State\<LogInScreen\> createState() =\> \_LogInScreenState();
}

class \_LogInScreenState extends State\<LogInScreen\> {
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.inversePrimary,
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Container(
          width: 400.0,
          height: 300.0,
          alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter, // Align content to the bottom
          child: Column(
            children: [
              TextField(
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                  labelText: 'Indtast dit CPR nummer',
                ),
              ),
              const SizedBox(
                  height: 30), // Adding space between TextField and Button
              ElevatedButton(
                onPressed: () async {
                  Navigator.push(
                    context,
                    MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => IntroScreen()),
                  );
                },
                style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                  backgroundColor: Colors.blue,
                  minimumSize: const Size(450, 50),
                ),
                child: Text(
                  'Log ind',
                  style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 20),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );

}
}
```

and yaml file:

```
description: "A new Flutter project."

# The following line prevents the package from being accidentally published to

# pub.dev using `flutter pub publish`. This is preferred for private packages.

publish_to: "none" # Remove this line if you wish to publish to pub.dev

# The following defines the version and build number for your application.

# A version number is three numbers separated by dots, like 1.2.43

# followed by an optional build number separated by a +.

# Both the version and the builder number may be overridden in flutter

# build by specifying --build-name and --build-number, respectively.

# In Android, build-name is used as versionName while build-number used as versionCode.

# Read more about Android versioning at https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/versioning

# In iOS, build-name is used as CFBundleShortVersionString while build-number is used as CFBundleVersion.

# Read more about iOS versioning at

# https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CoreFoundationKeys.html

# In Windows, build-name is used as the major, minor, and patch parts

# of the product and file versions while build-number is used as the build suffix.

version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
sdk: "\>=3.3.0 \<4.0.0"

# sdk: 3.3.1

# Dependencies specify other packages that your package needs in order to work.

# To automatically upgrade your package dependencies to the latest versions

# consider running `flutter pub upgrade --major-versions`. Alternatively,

# dependencies can be manually updated by changing the version numbers below to

# the latest version available on pub.dev. To see which dependencies have newer

# versions available, run `flutter pub outdated`.

dependencies:
flutter:
sdk: flutter

# The following adds the Cupertino Icons font to your application.

# Use with the CupertinoIcons class for iOS style icons.

cupertino_icons: ^1.0.6

audioplayers: 5.2.0

flutter_dotenv: ^5.0.2
flutter_audio_capture: ^1.1.4
assets_audio_player: ^3.0.8

dev_dependencies:
flutter_test:
sdk: flutter

# The "flutter_lints" package below contains a set of recommended lints to

# encourage good coding practices. The lint set provided by the package is

# activated in the `analysis_options.yaml` file located at the root of your

# package. See that file for information about deactivating specific lint

# rules and activating additional ones.

flutter_lints: ^3.0.0

# For information on the generic Dart part of this file, see the

# following page: https://dart.dev/tools/pub/pubspec

# The following section is specific to Flutter packages.

flutter:
assets:
\- assets/audio_files/
\- assets/text_strings/

# The following line ensures that the Material Icons font is

# included with your application, so that you can use the icons in

# the material Icons class.

uses-material-design: true

# To add assets to your application, add an assets section, like this:

# assets:

# - images/a_dot_burr.jpeg

# - images/a_dot_ham.jpeg

# An image asset can refer to one or more resolution-specific "variants", see

# https://flutter.dev/assets-and-images/#resolution-aware

# For details regarding adding assets from package dependencies, see

# https://flutter.dev/assets-and-images/#from-packages

# To add custom fonts to your application, add a fonts section here,

# in this "flutter" section. Each entry in this list should have a

# "family" key with the font family name, and a "fonts" key with a

# list giving the asset and other descriptors for the font. For

# example:

# fonts:

# - family: Schyler

# fonts:

# - asset: fonts/Schyler-Regular.ttf

# - asset: fonts/Schyler-Italic.ttf

# style: italic

# - family: Trajan Pro

# fonts:

# - asset: fonts/TrajanPro.ttf

# - asset: fonts/TrajanPro_Bold.ttf

# weight: 700

# 

# For details regarding fonts from package dependencies,

# see https://flutter.dev/custom-fonts/#from-packages
```

Before switching to 6.0.0, I was using the previous version of audioplayers (5.2.0), but I got another error:

> [ERROR:flutter/shell/common/shell.cc(1038)] The 'xyz.luan/audioplayers/events/3b0f4bf9-8472-47d4-9b0b-44834d2e2182' channel sent a message from native to Flutter on a non-platform thread. Platform channel messages must be sent on the platform thread. Failure to do so may result in data loss or crashes, and must be fixed in the plugin or application code creating that channel.
> See https://docs.flutter.dev/platform-integration/platform-channels#channels-and-platform-threading for more information.``